# Why is ctrl+~ not working in vscode on linux?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press `Ctrl+~` to open the terminal in vscode, instead it will show notifications.

How can I find out which program is intercepting this key combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+~` is actually `` Ctrl+` ``

And by default is bound to showing **dunst** history, check `~/.config/dunst/dunstrc` to see the following line is there under the `[shortcuts]`:

```
   history = ctrl+shift+grave
```

If that's not it, then the problem is probably you're looking for the `~` (tilde), instead of the `` ` `` character.

From: https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/ctrl-does-not-work-on-i3/12645

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question there is a way to troubleshoot keybinding issues.  See [VSCode Wiki: Keybinding Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues#:%7E:text=Basic%20Troubleshooting%20Run%20the%20command%20Developer%3A%20Toggle%20Keyboard,VS%20Code%20detects%20and%20what%20command%20is%20invoked.).

In your case you could run the command `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` (from the Command Palette) and you presumably would have seen the <kbd>Ctlr</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> resolved to some other command with the **source** being listed as the extension which overrode the built-in command.